Common Tangent to hyperbola and circle using parametric coordinates
The circle $x^2+y^2-8x=0$ and hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{9}-\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ are given
Find equation of a common tangent with positive slope to the circle as well as to the hyperbola is
(A) $2x - \sqrt{5}y - 20 = 0$
(B) $2x - \sqrt{5}y +4 = 0$
(C) $3x - 4y + 8 = 0$
(D) $4x - 3y + 4 = 0$
My solution=
I formed the parametric equation for the hyperbola .
$\frac{\sec{\theta}}{3} - \frac{\tan{\theta}}{2}=1$
Then equate the perpendicular distance between the centre of the given circle to the radius of the circle .
On solving the equation further  a quadratic in $\sec{\theta}$ is formed .. on solving it I get two value of sec theta i.e $\frac{-3}{2}$ and $\frac{5}{6}$ .
I can only use $\sec{\theta} = \frac{-3}{2}$ as the other value is not possible .
Since $\sec{\theta}$ is negative, theta is in either 2nd or 3rd quadrant but since it is mentioned in the question that slope is positive , that means $\tan{\theta}$ is positive . Hence the angle in in 3rd quadrant.
So I put the values of sec and tan in the equation formed at the very first step . But I am getting
$2x+\sqrt{5}y+4 =0$ . But the given answer is $2x-\sqrt{5}y+4=0$ .
Can someone please explain my mistake ?

Do you allow to use Lagrangian multiplier?

Your method is correct. But you have chosen one of two symmetric branches by $\frac{\sec{\theta}}{3} - \frac{\tan{\theta}}{2}=1$. Note that the solution is not unique.

@MathArt really bro... Lagrange multiplier for this question!!!!

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, You are right. totally agree! But if the purpose is just to solve this problem, even hand drawing can find the choice. Applying Lagrangian method is for fun...

@MathArt i see

Strictly speaking, the eccentric angle $\theta$ of the hyperbola shall be consistent with the tangent line definition. Please note you will not get tangent to right brunch of parabola.

Is there a way that I can find the other tangent through the same method ?

Ok, Cesareo have shown you in graph.

Also you can play with the parameters here https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/rhdt25nf.

The equation of the tangent is $$\frac{x}{3}\sec \theta-\frac{y}{2}\tan \theta=1$$
The perpendicular distance from the centre of the circle should be equal to radius. So, $$\frac{\left|\frac{4}{3}\sec\theta-1\right|}{\sqrt{\frac{\sec^2\theta}{9}+\frac{\tan^2\theta}{4}}}=4$$
Solving this quadratic gives $\sec\theta=-\frac{3}{2}$ 
$\implies \tan\theta=\frac{-\sqrt5}{2}$
Because the slope of this line is $\frac{2}{3}\csc\theta$ which has to be greater than $0$. So we must have $\theta$ in second quadrant.
After this you'll get the required equation, $$\boxed{2x-\sqrt{5}y+4=0}$$

Of course it's possible to find the other tangent. We have $\sec\theta=-3/2$ so we have $\tan^2\theta=5/4$ now if we don't want the slope positive, i.e. we want all tangents then we simply have two values of $\tan\theta$ and one value of $\sec\theta$. Just putting them in the original equation yeilds two equations (of tangnets).

Found my mistake. Thanks alot

Is there a way that I can find the other tangent through the same method ?

@Nandini I have updated my answer

Got it ! Thanks alot

Using tangency properties.
Given a circle $\mathscr{C}$, a hyperbola $\mathscr{H}$ and a line $\mathscr{L}$ which is tangent to both $\{\mathscr{C}, \mathscr{H}\}$ as
$$
\cases{
\mathscr{C}\to x^2+y^2-8x=0\\
\mathscr{H}\to \frac{x^2}{9}-\frac{y^2}{4}-1=0\\
\mathscr{L}\to y- m x + c = 0
}
$$
after eliminating in both $y$, we have at tangency:
$$
\cases{
\{\mathscr{C},\mathscr{L} \}\to c^2 - 8 x + 2 c m x + x^2 + m^2 x^2 = p_1(x) = 0\\
\{\mathscr{H},\mathscr{L} \}\to 36 + 9 c^2 + 18 c m x - 4 x^2 + 9 m^2 x^2= p_2(x) = 0
}
$$
but due to tangency,
$$
\cases{
p_1(x) = c_1(x-x_1)^2\\
p_2(x) = c_2(x-x_2)^2\\
}\ \ \ \ \forall x
$$
or equivalently
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 c^2-c_1 x_1^2 & = & 0\\
 2 c m+2 c_1 x_1-8 & = & 0 \\
 m^2+1 -c_1 & = & 0\\
 9 c^2-c_2 x_2^2+36  & = & 0\\
 18 c m+2 c_2 x_2  & = & 0\\
 9 m^2-4-c_2 & = & 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Solving for $\{m,c,c_1,c_2,x_1,x_2\}$ we obtain:
$$
\cases{
\mathscr{L}_1 \to y = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\\
\mathscr{L}_2 \to y = -\frac{2x}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\\
}
$$

NOTE
To solve this system we begin eliminating $\{c_1,c_2\}$ after that we follow eliminating $\{x_1,x_2\}$ arriving at
$$
\cases{
c^2 + 8 c m - 16 = 0\\
4 + c^2 - 9 m^2 = 0
}
$$
and finally
$$
\cases{
 495 m^4+104 m^2-400  = 0\\
55 c^4+544 c^2 -2304 = 0
}
$$

Solving those equations manually is not feasible

Please. See included note.
